# how to create md5 for a big file in erlang? crypto:md5

Tags: erlang

I want to create md5 for a big size file. The erlang:md5/1's parameter is 'Data'. Because the filesize is big, so it is not suitable to read the whole data into memory.

How to do it?

In addition, In the [mongodb-gridfs](https://github.com/hammingweight/mongo_gridfs.git) project， I have found the following code

```
%@doc Inserts a file with a specified bson document into the default bucket.
%     The file contents can be passed as either data or a file process opened for
%     reading.

Md5 = list_to_binary(bin_to_hexstr(crypto:md5(FileData))),
```

The parameter could be io_device.

```
3> {ok,Io_device} = file:open("test.beam",write).
{ok,<0.60.0>}

8> Io_device.                 
<0.60.0>
9> crypto:md5(Io_device).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  crypto:md5/1
        called as crypto:md5(<0.60.0>)
```

The shell reminds that the argument is error, why?

Comment: The parameter to `crypto:md5/1` is of `iodata()` type which is a list of bytes and binaries. Not `iodevice()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read file in chunks and use either http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#md5_final-1 :

- `erlang:md5_init/0`,
- `erlang:md5_update/2`,
- `erlang:md5_final/1`.

Or http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#hash-2 :

- `crypto:hash_init(md5)`
- `crypto:hash_update/2`
- `crypto:hash_final/1`.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Elixir, the function to hash a large file in Elixir using the functions from Dmitry's answer is:

```
  def hash_large_file(path, algorithm \\ :md5) do
    path
    |> File.stream!([], 16_384)
    |> Enum.reduce(:crypto.hash_init(algorithm), fn chunk, digest ->
      :crypto.hash_update(digest, chunk)
    end)
    |> :crypto.hash_final()
    |> Base.encode16()
  end
```

and these are the [hash names as atoms](http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#type-hash_algorithm)